# Cannot assign 'Open With' to a specific application using Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, finder, coda

I am using Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and Coda 2.0.4.

I want all my .js files to open with Coda (currently js files are assigned to Safari).

When I do a 'Get Info' and change the 'Open with' application I try to select Coda 2 but it immediately bounces back to Safari.

If I choose any other application, like Firefox, XCode, etc it takes it. It only seems to hate Coda 2.

Any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rebuilding the Launch Services database by running `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed`?

If that doesn't work, you could also try `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=com.netscape.javascript-source;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.panic.Coda;}'`. Applying the changes requires restarting (logging out and back in isn't enough).

Comment: Lauri the first method returns a non-existing folder message. The 2nd method did run but after restart I still have the same problem. how frustrating...

Comment: I edited the first command. The path changed in some version of OS X, but I copied the older one.